# Mobile Menu with Bootstrap close on click Nav Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really sorry I sent the wrong link! This is how my code looks:

```js
    jQuery("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed site page-container"><div id="sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu nav navbar-nav sidebar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu links</a></li>
</ul></div><div class="navbar"><div class="navbar-header pull-left">
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i> MENU</a></div></div> 
<div id="content page-content-wrapper" class="site-content">
<div id="primary" class="content-area-wide">
<div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
  Main area
  </div></div></div></div></div>
```

It should close when clicking on a menu link. How can I achieve this?

Comment: share the code what you have tried using jsfiddle.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this. hope this helps. I changed my post!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
jQuery("ul.nav li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Matei, why are you preventingDefault? And what happens when you click the menu on a desktop?